# Are these two Barons von Dammenblatz the same person?

Tags: published-adventures, lore, npc, wfrp-4e

The first story of [*Rough Nights & Hard Days*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PV451BX) has the protagonist Baron **Eberhardt** von Dammenblatz of Wissenberg.

The fourth book's cover blurb mentions Baron **Otto** von Dammenblatz from [*White Dwarf*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Dwarf_(magazine)) #94 (Nov. 1987), the first iteration of this story.

I tried to find other occurrences of the Eberhardt name but even this extensive [character list](http://hobbithole.chez.com/encyc.htm) mentions only Baron von Dammenblatz, and this is too vague to be useful.

- Are Baron Otto and Baron Eberhardt different people? Or was one of the names officially changed to the other?
- *White Dwarf* #94 says that Baron Otto von Dammenblatz is from Wissenb**u**rg and not Wissenb**e**rg. Are these (or should they be) the same place?

Official word on this matter is preferred.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### These two Barons von Dammenblatz are the same person and the correct name is Baron *Eberhardt* von Dammenblatz.

I ask [Cubicle7 by Email](https://www.cubicle7games.com/about-us/contact-us/) and here is the answer :

> Actually, the flaw is in the original from WD 94. The first mention of von
> Dammenblatz calls him Otto, and on the very next page his name is changed to Eberhardt. All these years and no
> one caught that. The error is perpetuated in Plundered Vaults, and finally corrected in RN&HD.

And about Wissenb**u**rg and Wissenb**e**rg:

> The spelling of Wissenburg/Wissenberg is one of many instances of
> names and locations changing in various iterations of the Old World.
> The best known are the various locations of Delberz and the spelling
> of Immelscheld/Immelscheid, both of which I intended to address in the
> Director's Cut.
>
> Anyhow, this one can easily be but down to scribal
> error on the part of some cartographer's apprentice charged with
> lettering the map. The Old World is a pre-literate society on the
> whole, and spelling is various, as it was in the real Middle Ages and
> Renaissance."

I also found this:

> - burg = castle
> - berg = mountain
>
> Both words are derived from bergen which means something like to be in
> a safe position. Way back when, a human fortress and natural defences
> like mountains both offer high ground (advantageous attack and vantage
> point) and thus relative safety.

Sources:
[image: Are these two Barrons von Dammenblatz the same person ? asked to cubicle7 by email]

[image: Are these two Barrons von Dammenblatz the same person ? Answer from cubicle7 by email]

- [What is the difference between burg and berg in German city
  names?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-burg-and-berg-in-German-city-names)
- [wiktionary: burg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burg)